# What permission should set to the directory to avoid Permission Denied?

Tags: python

I'm using python manage.py runserver in development mode and getting

```
IOError at /cmanager/upload/save
[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/tmp/temp/IMG_27022014_183050.png'
```

Once I run the `chmod -R 775 "/tmp/temp/"`, it works. But on every shutdown/restart of computer, that directory from /tmp gets deleted automatically, Since need to create it manually.

settings.py

```
CONTENT_STORAGE_PATH    /tmp/temp/
```

controller

```
if not os.path.exists(settings.CONTENT_STORAGE_PATH):
    try:
        os.makedirs(settings.CONTENT_STORAGE_PATH, 0644)
    except OSError, e:
       self.raiseException(e)
content_storage_path = os.path.join(settings.\
                                          CONTENT_STORAGE_PATH, f.name)
with open(content_storage_path, 'wb+') as destination:
       for chunk in f.chunks():
         destination.write(chunk)
```

How to avoid this `Permission Denied` error.

Is it good to set permissions? like: `os.chmod(content_storage_path, 0600)`. If so what it should be? `0775`?

**Note**: I'm going to change the location `"/tmp/temp/"` to `"/var/www/temp/"` in production mode while configuring with `Apache/NginX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good to set permissions with `os.chmod` inside your script, because you can not escalate priveleges any higher than whatever the process itself has.

I don't think you should be using `os` module at all here.  Use builtin `tempfile` module for a tried-and-tested cross-platform method of doing what you need.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html

If your permission issues remain, you need to resolve them outside the script - they are environment issues and not the responsibility of the code.